# Is there a way to step through the DOM loading?

Tags: javascript, dom, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

I am working on a site and I have set up some responsive rules. After a certain point there seems to be an odd grey shape that appears for a second and then goes away.

Is it possible to step through the DOM as the elements load? I am having trouble figuring out what element is causing this, it obviously is something that I am altering, but can't lock it down.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: I would delete blocks of HTML from a certain point onward, then reload, until I've isolated when the grey shape appears.

Comment: @Blazemonger Yeah, I am thinking about that, I was hoping there might be an easier solution though! Maybe not. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will work, but you could try putting something like this near the top of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
debugger;
</script>
```

Comment: That just seems to break on that and only that sadly, DOM still loads. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `--show-paint-rect` option in chrome.

Check out this video by Paul Irish: [Viewing Painting Behavior w/ Chrome DevTools](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ea41RdQ1oFQ)

<s>I haven't try it for a while though, not sure how supported it is in current version...</s>

**Edit:**

Ok, it seems like they moved it into Dev Tools. Having Developer Tools displayed, click on the settings icon (bottom right corner of the tools panel). There is "Show paint rectangles" check box. After checking it, you can reload your page to see the way it was rendered.

Original implementation of this seemed to be a bit more efficient, though.

Comment: Yeah, I had seen the move to the Dev tool a little while ago, I like it have it on, I can see it paint, but then of course it disappears, I think my solution is a combination of removing elements and this. Thanks for the suggestion though!